# Could not load file or assembly 'System.text.json' , version 4.0.1.0

Tags: c#, json, ssis

I have created an SSIS package in VS 2019 to consume an API, doing deserialization using System.Text.Json. It works perfectly when I execute it locally but when I deployed it to SQL Server (SQL Server 2019) and run it as an SQL Job it fails with the error:
**"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version 4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken = cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies'."**

Where do i have to look for if this file/assembly on the server? or what I need to do to get it to work?

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-assembly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I tried that which pulled me into the circle of assembly hell:
1st error: Assembly 'System.Text.Json' references assembly 'system.memiory, version=4.1.4.0, which is not present in the current database.

2nd error: Assembly 'System.Text.Json' references assembly 'system.numerics.vectors, version=4.1.4.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.', which is not present in the current database.

Not sure what to do now.

Comment: Is .NET Framework installed on the server? Your assembly needs the runtime to work.

Comment: I compared .Netframework between my machine and the server, I have 4.8.4084.0 and the server is showing 4.7.3062.0, I have informed the Infrastructure team to look at, maybe that's the issue.